# Running Bash Shell through Cygwin64 command line creates file with funny character in name

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I am very new to cygwin64 and bash. We currently run mkpasswd in cygwin64 manually but i'd like to do it as a windows batch job or via powershell.

To do this I run the command line below

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -i "f:\temp\script.bsh"
```

The contents of script.bsh are

```
    mkpasswd -d -cl > "/home/ouradmin/users"
```

It all works fine except the file that is created is not called users. It's actually users. It puts this weird unicode character at the end.

Can anyone please tell me how to eliminate this.

Comment: Save your script as a UNIX text file, not a DOS text file. Your character almost certainly isn't actually unicode, but just a `$'\r'` -- a CR, aka a carriage return. This is because DOS text files end in CRLF, whereas UNIX text files end only in LF, so when a UNIX process reads a DOS text file, it sees an extra CR at the end.

Comment: That did the trick.